# "if else not working for selenium python in find_elements_by_xpath"

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, xpath

for each_job in job_list:
job_company = each_job.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='company']")[0]
job_location = each_job.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='location accessible-contrast-color-location']")[0]

```
if each_job.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='salaryText']").is_displayed():
    job_salary = each_job.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='salaryText']")[0]
else:
    job_salary = "Not Mentioned"
    
job_summary = each_job.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='summary']")[0]
```

Comment: Please help me to find the xpath of  class if not present and add a "Not Available" value if class item not available

Comment: If you need to revise your question, edit it (use the Edit link bottom left). Don't tack your revisions on as comments.